# Delphi 7 IDE - Index out of bounds in list read access

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-7

One of my delphi projects produces this error message when closing the IDE.

**Note** This is not the same as 'List Index out of bounds(0)' error.

[image]

Then it always shows another error: 'Invalid Pointer Operation'

[image]

Any ideas how i could locate where it is coming from?

Comment: re: "one of project" - that gives an idea: which component(s) in your project makes this project so special? In other words - used in this project but not in the others. Find it and your issues will be pinpointed to design-time package of this component.

Comment: Why worry about this? I'd just ignore it since it only happens on shut down.

Comment: @David: Because it's an IDE issue that can destabilize the IDE? And because, since most of these types of issues are the result of buggy third-party components, there may be other things in the code that may not have shown itself yet. Resolving this may lead to your finding other issues.

Comment: @Ken I spent many years developing on D6 with such issues. If it's a bug in the Delphi code then only Andreas H can fix it!

Comment: :) That's not what I meant. You can have third-party (or your own) comps, experts, etc., that are buggy that can destabilize the IDE and cause what appear to be totally unrelated issues in your projects. These make it difficult, because you end up looking in the wrong place and wasting a lot of time and effort. (I've been using Delphi since D1, and for almost 7 years sold a commercial component/code library - I have a little experience with tracking down strange errors in the IDE. <g>)

Comment: This is actually a cause of another issue i am having with the same project - i can only compile and run it once before it locks up on subsequent compilations - and i have to force quit the IDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds either like an IDE bug, or (more likely) like a bug in a component.

**Fix and speedup the IDE**

Install the [latest official IDE hotfix](http://cc.embarcadero.com/reg/delphi) (I guess Delphi 7 latest update is 7.1).

Download and install [DelphiSpeedUp 3.1](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/delphispeedup/).

It may fix some issues, and will in fact make your IDE faster. Worth trying it.

**Component issue**

Could you uninstall all installed third-party components?

Then reinstall your custom packages one by one, checking which one triggers the error.

It's possible that some bug in the IDE editor part of some third-party component occurs at IDE closing.

Comment: Thanks A.Bouchez... I have done the first two already, but you may be onto something regarding a third party component. When i get a chance i will try uninstalling component packages

Comment: I disapprove DelphiSpeedUp recommendation, it will more likely add issues or mask them, and unlikely will help locating ones.

Comment: @Downvoter DelphiSpeedUp don't add issues, but solve some, and move remaining. As stated by Andy's page: "*Not every access violation in DelphiSpeedUp.dll is a bug in DelphiSpeedUp. Actually many of the exceptions in the RTL package are now thrown in the DelphiSpeedUp.dll because the RTL functions are replaced by the DelphiSpeedUp functions and wrong parameters like nil-pointers, invalid pointers, … now lead to access violations in the replacement code. A wrong function call just remains a wrong function call.*"

Comment: @A.Bouchez, i'm little less confident about DelphiSpeedUp :-) At best it will have no effect in locating troublesome code.

Comment: @David Heffernan, my experience with Herr Hausladen's closed-source product is limited to spurious `GraphicFilter`s added by one of early version. For the (long!) lecture on non-positive impact of adding some good but opaque influence to problematic system you should give several beers to some telecom engineer :-)

Comment: @David Heffernan, sorry i've got a plural disease when talking in the Lord's language. What specifically you are not able to understand?

Comment: @David Heffernan, no worries at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the Delphi IDE in its own debugger (menu `Run`, `Load Process`, then choose the the IDE executable - delphi32.exe in your case). Then reproduce the problem with this project. You might get a hint where the problem is located.

Answer (score 1):

"Invalid pointer operation" means you freed memory that didn't belong to you. One of these three things is the cause:

- Your program freed something that had already been freed once before.
- Your program freed something that was never allocated in the first place.
- Your program freed something that had been allocated with a different memory manager.

Comment: Is it definately my program though? This happens when closing my project within the IDE (or closing the IDE), not closing my application when it is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [madExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm). Then it shows detailed information (callstack and more) about the exception and you might be able to locate the origin.

Comment: I already have EurekaLog, and unfortunately it does not catch this exception since it is generated through the IDE on closing (and im assuming after EurekaLog is unloaded

Comment: @Simon: MadExcept can be configured to catch most (not all) exceptions in the IDE as well.